# How to import PubNub

Tags: pubnub

Hello I import Pubnub in my python file I already installed Pubnub in python env, it's installed just fine  but when I try to be import,it's not imported in my python file, Can anybody help me
below I also attach some screenshots[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5cPG.png)

Comment: Did you either install it or put it in `requirements.txt` like the [docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/python) say?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [PubNub Python Docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/python):

Install pubnub using `pip`:

```
pip install 'pubnub>=7.0.0'
```

In your python main add:

```
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub

pnconfig = PNConfiguration()

pnconfig.subscribe_key = 'mySubscribeKey'
pnconfig.publish_key = 'myPublishKey'
pnconfig.user_id = "my_custom_user_id"
pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)
```

Remember to always set your `user_id` in the `pnconfig` object.

Finally, add the callback listeners like in this full sample: [PubNub Python Putting it together](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/python#putting-it-all-together)